# how to list the dependencies of a maven plugin within in a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-plugin-development

with

```
List<Plugin> plugins = project.getBuild().getPlugins();
```

I can get all plugins.

```
plugin.getDependencies()
```

only delivers the dependencies declared when using it.
But how can I get the (transitive) list of the dependencies of each plugin ?
The dependencies necessary to build it.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What would you like to achive?

Comment: @ khmarbaise I want to look at the full tree of dependencies necessary to build an artifact. And then determine their licenses.

Comment: The dependencies to build an artifact is already done by Maven etc. for license i would recommend to take a look at http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/

Comment: @khmarbaise a) Of  course this is done by maven, otherwise the plugin can not run. I just want this list. b) I know the license-maven-plugin. I want to do a bit more and I am not sure it looks at plugin dependencies.

Comment: The plugin dependencies usually are not a problem cause they will never become part of your product...?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am fully with you here. I am worried a bit about the "usually" part, i.e. a followup question would be: Is there a prossibility that a plugins license may restrict its use or the result ?

Comment: Could be...to be honest never seen such plugin. Furthermore if i like to use a plugin i take a look before if it does not have MIT, APL i will not use it...But of course that could have an impact...sure.